# Implementing Twilio Api call from a CURL example to js returns status code of 200 but does not seem to update data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, twilio

I am trying to update my sim fleet name and sim unique name without any success

```
  const url = `https://supersim.twilio.com/v1/Sims/${sid}? fleet=${fleet}&uniqueName=${uniqueName}`;


  const resp = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: auth.twilioAuth,
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }),
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      Iccid: iccid,
    }).toString(),
  });
```

I get a 200 response with my sim object as follows

```
account_sid: "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
date_created: "2022-01-08T21:05:00Z"
date_updated: "2022-01-08T21:05:00Z"
fleet_sid: null  //did not update
iccid: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
links: {billing_periods: 'https://supersim.twilio.com/v1/Sims/HSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BillingPeriods'}
sid: "HSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
status: "new"
unique_name: null  //did not update
url: "https://supersim.twilio.com/v1/Sims/HSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

[Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/api/sim-resource)

and this is what their CURL example website says

```
curl -X POST https://wireless.twilio.com/v1/Sims/DEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
--data-urlencode "CallbackMethod=POST" \
--data-urlencode "CallbackUrl=https://sim-manager.mycompany.com/sim-update-callback/AliceSmithSmartMeter" \
--data-urlencode "Status=active" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the parameters you want to update in the body of the request, not in the query parameters. Also note that [the parameter names](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/api/sim-resource#update-a-sim-resource) are in [Pascal case](https://www.theserverside.com/answer/Pascal-case-vs-camel-case-Whats-the-difference). Try this:

```js
  const url = `https://supersim.twilio.com/v1/Sims/${sid}`;

  const resp = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: auth.twilioAuth,
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }),
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      Iccid: iccid,
      Fleet: fleet,
      UniqueName: uniqueName
    }).toString(),
  });
```